# Memory crash on sending 100MB+ file to S3 on chrome

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-chrome, amazon-s3

I'm currently using Javascript to upload some video files to S3. The process works for files <100MB, but for ~100MB plus on chrome I run into an error (this works on safari). I am using ManagedUpload in this example which [should](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html) be doing `multipart/form-data` in the background.

Code snippet:

```
...
        let upload = new AWS.S3.ManagedUpload({
            params:{
                    Bucket:  'my-bucket',
                    Key:   videoFileName,
                    Body:  videoHere,
                    ACL:  "public-read"
            }
        });
        upload.promise();
        
...
```

Chrome crashes with the error `RESULT_CODE_INVALID_CMDLINE_URL`, dev tools crash and in the Chrome terminal logs i get this:

```
[5573:0x3000000000]    27692 ms: Scavenge 567.7 (585.5) -> 567.7 (585.5) MB, 23.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.995, current mu = 0.768) allocation failure 
[5573:0x3000000000]    28253 ms: Mark-sweep 854.6 (872.4) -> 609.4 (627.1) MB, 235.8 / 0.0 ms  (+ 2.3 ms in 2 steps since start of marking, biggest step 1.4 ms, walltime since start of marking 799 ms) (average mu = 0.940, current mu = 0.797) allocation fa

<--- JS stacktrace --->

[5573:775:0705/140126.808951:FATAL:memory.cc(38)] Out of memory. size=0
[0705/140126.813085:WARNING:process_memory_mac.cc(93)] mach_vm_read(0x7ffee4199000, 0x2000): (os/kern) invalid address (1)
[0705/140126.880084:WARNING:system_snapshot_mac.cc(42)] sysctlbyname kern.nx: No such file or directory (2)
```

I've tried using HTTP PUT also, both work for smaller files but once i get bigger they both crash.

Any ideas? I've been through tons of SO posts / AWS docs but nothing helped this issue yet.

Edit: I've filed the issue with Chrome; seems like its an actual bug. Will update post when I have an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue came from loading the big file into memory (several times) which would crash chrome before it even had a chance to upload.

The fix was using `createObjectURL` (a url pointing to the file) instead of `readAsDataUrl` (the entire file itself), and when sending the file to your API, use `const newFile = new File([await fetch(objectURL).then(req => req.blob()], 'example.mp4', {type: 'video/mp4'});`

This worked for me as I was doing many conversions to get `readAsDataUrl` to the file type i wanted, but in this way i use much less space.