# aws-sdk client-s3 Upload: chrome crash after 8 GB of upload

Tags: javascript, typescript, aws-sdk

I want upload from browser a 17 GB file, but after 8 GB chrome crash for memory exhaustion

```
import { PutObjectCommandInput, S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import { Progress, Upload } from "@aws-sdk/lib-storage";

const uploadParams: PutObjectCommandInput = {
  Bucket: 'my-bucket',
  Key: 'my-file',
  Body: file, // is File from <input type="file">
};

const upload: Upload = new Upload({
  client: s3Client,
  params: uploadParams,
});

// start upload
await upload.done();
```

what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you upload the file manually using `fetch` _without_ going through Amazon's S3 client lib? (e.g. doing a `Range`-based upload)? Also, it's possible that the S3 client lib just doesn't support large uploads?

Comment: What exactly is your `file` object in this case? Are you using the DOM's streaming `File` (or `Blob`) objects, or are you loading it entirely into memory yourself?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62747820/memory-crash-on-sending-100mb-file-to-s3-on-chrome

Comment: @Dai file is File

Comment: But how/where are you getting the `File` from?

Comment: Also, Amazon's own S3 troubleshooting page recommends breaking large files up and using multipart uploads: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-large-file-uploads/ and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpuoverview.html (it seems S3 reuses the term "multipart" to mean something else than HTTP's `multipart/`, curious... and confusing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS S3 has a [5GB size limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/upload-objects.html) on a single PUT operation.

You need to initiate a [multi-part upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpuoverview.html) and split the file into chunks (5GB for example) before uploading - this *may* also resolve your Chrome crashing.

Even if Chrome did not crash, your code wouldn't work as it is - chunk up the file and upload them one by one.